# Exclude event if already registered for it

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make it where people are able to register for events and view all the events, but I want to make it where if they view the event page it will not show the events that they have already registered for it will exclude them.

I'm storing the events people are registered for in the table called 
tournament_registration

in this table it stores the tournamentid, their userid, firstname,lastname, phonenumber.

and the event details in 
tournament

I'm able to select all of the events details from the tournament database.

This is what I have so far.

```
 <?php
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM tournaments');
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    ?>      

                    <!-- OVERVIEW -->

                <div class="panel panel-headline">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title">  <? echo $row['tournament_name']; ?></h3>
                                    <p class="panel-subtitle">
                                    Event Date: <? echo $row['tournament_date'];?>
                                    <br>
                                     Event Start time: <? echo $row['tournament_time'];?>
                                     <br>
                                     Event Entry Fee: 
                                     <? echo $row['entryfee'];?>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <h4>Panel Content</h4>
                                    <p>
                                     <? echo $row['tournament_desc'];?>

                                    </p>
                                    <a href="signup.php?do=<?php echo $row['tournamentid'];?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register for this event </button></a>

                                </div>
                            </div>


<?
}
?>
```

Any Ideas on how I'm able to exclude the events the user is already registered for?

Comment: In a new table (eg called `registered_event` or whatever) store an event_id and user_id in the same row for each event they have registered to. Then check this table with their user_id and don't show events where they have already registered.

Comment: @James `$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM tournaments WHERE tournamentid !='.$row['tournament_regid'].'');` This is What I came up and it works! Just exclude the regid which is the tournamentid.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: @tadman how do you != :registered ? Because it came up with an error when I tried to use a prepared statement.

Comment: @tadman Never mind it works now. It was giving me an error earlier when I tried to do a prepared statement. This is what I came up with. `$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM tournaments WHERE tournamentid !=:registered');
$stmt->bindParam(':registered', $row['tournament_regid']);`

Comment: That looks right, but remember you can pass in arguments to `execute` directly, like `execute([ ':registered' => $row['...'] ])` to simplify things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can exclude the rows in the SQL query.

In place of `SELECT * FROM tournaments`

We can use a query with an anti-join pattern:

```
SELECT t.tournament_date
     , t.tournament_time
     , t.entryfee
     , t.tournament_desc
     , t.tournamentid
  FROM tournaments t
    -- anti-join
  LEFT
  JOIN tournament_registration r
    ON r.tournamentid = t.tournamentid
   AND r.user_id = ?
 WHERE r.tournmaentid IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY ...
```

-or- a not exists pattern

```
SELECT t.tournament_date
     , t.tournament_time
     , t.entryfee
     , t.tournament_desc
     , t.tournamentid
  FROM tournaments t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                      FROM tournament_registration r
                     WHERE r.tournamentid = t.tournamentid
                       AND r.user_id = ?
                  )
 ORDER
    BY ...
```

We will need to pass in the value of the user_id.

```
$stmt->execute($user_id);
```

and the value will be provided in place of the `?` question mark placeholder in the query text.

Or we can use a named placeholder in the SQL text

```
   AND r.user_id = :registered_user
```

And after the prepared, and before the execute, we can do a `bindValue`

```
  $stmt->bindValue(':registered_user',$user_id);
```

then followed by the execute.

No other changes to the code are required.

Comment: This is a more thorough answer than my own, and removes the `SELECT *` in favor of explicitly declared fields. ++

Comment: @slothluvchunk: I can't in good conscience post SQL that doesn't qualify column references, or uses `*` in the SELECT list place of an explicit list of expressions to be returned. (II will use `a.*` in a SELECT list, but only when the columns in `a` are defined within the query i.e. when `a` is an inline view.)

Comment: Agreed - it was a good move, hence my support for it. :) It's easy to get in the habit of suggesting solutions without addressing anything else, and I appreciate your thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the "relationship" already built, with the `tournament_registration` table, then you can use your query statement to filter out those users.

`$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM tournaments');` could instead be something like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM 
          tournaments as t, 
          tournament_registration as tr 
        WHERE 
          t.userid = tr.userid';
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
```

In this example, an implicit join will return only the results from `tournaments` and `tournament_registration` that share the same userid, which should be your desired list of tournaments/events that a given user is signed up for.
*note* - You'll want to limit this query further by a specific event ID, or a specific user ID depending on how you'd like to iterate over this data in your view.